# Converting android apps to blackberry : Updates lose stored data within the phone

Tags: android, blackberry, adt, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I need my `Android` application to work in `Blackberry` platform and followed the following process (explained under the blackberry deve zone) to convert existing Android app to work in blackberry.

[Runtime for Android apps](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/)

So I can create a `.bar` file and continue my work.

I am currently using the blackberry simulator with VMWare downloaded from following links.

[BB 10 Simulator](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/simulator/index.html) & [VMWare](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0)

My Android app(Converted) works well in Blackberry but experiencing a small isuue and needs to get this clarified.

When I run the application for the first time, I need to store some user settings and also some information later with the app usage (within the phone itself).

So in android I used sharedpreferences and Sqlite DB to store a small amount of data within the phone. But when I do a modification in the code and and re-install it (basically Run the application from eclipse to update existing app) to the BB emulator without un-installing existing APP, it loses all the stored data within the phone.

Wonder if this issue (losing stored data when update App) going to continue in the similar way with marketplace (Blackberry world) updates as well. **OR** do I do any mistake here to lose the stored information when I run eclipse project to update the App in Simulator?

A giude in this would be really aprreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There are three possibilities. On Momentics (I don't have the Eclipse Android/BlackBerry 10 plugin to check), in your run configuration settings, you can change the way the application is installed: replacing the old one, uninstalling the old one then installing it again, ... maybe you can check this.
A second possibility is that you changed your app ID in the descriptor: it will look like two different applications for the phone.
A last possibility is that all settings are effectively lost on upgrade... But I don't think so. It's not the case with native apps.